# Как один path вычесть из другого path

Tags: javascript, css, svg, математика, геометрия

Я пытаюсь найти способ вычесть один path SVG из другого path, аналогично как работает в Illustrator `inverse clip mask`.
Я не могу использовать фильтры, потому что мне нужно будет найти точки пересечения составного path с другими path. Illustrator делает это с помощью инструмента поиска пути `minus front` следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Path красного квадрата до вычитания:

`<rect class="cls-1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="184.93" height="178.08"/>`

После вычитания:

`<polygon class="cls-1" points="112.83 52.55 185.43 52.55 185.43 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 178.58 112.83 178.58 112.83 52.55"/>`

Мне нужно это для работы со всеми типами фигур, включая кривые. Если это имеет значение, все входные SVG будут преобразованы в универсальные (path) пути.

Как выполнить **программно** вычитание одной фигуры (path) из другой фигуры (path)?

P.S
***Ответы, как это сделать в графических редакторах,- не интересуют.***

Comment: Собственно ничего кроме стандартного поиска точек пересечения и нет. С кривыми чуть сложнее, там может быть больше одной точки пересечения, но в общем то они тоже вычисляются.

Comment: Думаю начать надо с приведения координат точек всех фигур, в единую систему координат. После этого, можно воспользоваться математическими методами нахождения пересечения фигур. Для выпуклых фигур нужно просто вычесть одни координаты из других. В общем когда у вас фигуры заданы точками понятно что делать. Но я убей не пойму, как вы будете вычислять все это, когда у вас фигура будет задана кривыми. По идее вам нужно будет приравнивать уравнение одной кривой к другой, находить корни уравнения и определять, лежит ли точка внутри фигур.

Comment: На английском SO разбирали этот вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847082/subtracting-svg-paths-programmatically

Comment: Наверно ни как..

Comment: @AndreiFedorov в  svg внутри не бывает, поверх только..слой на слое..если не ошибусь то внутри группы можнт быть..на js это ни сделать..возможно пайтон или пыхе может быть есть либа какая то

Comment: @РезидентКазахстана в svg внутри не бывает, зато в математике бывает.